# Is there a template for migrating Hasura migrations & metadata with gitlab ci

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, hasura

I would like to migrate my Hasura managed database schemas and metadata with gitlab's CI, but there doesn't appear to be a specific example of a .gitlab-ci.yml out there.

Answer (score 0):

This is what we've come up with for a .gitlab-ci.yml file.

```
image: debian:stable-slim

stages:
  - migrate
variables:
  HASURA_VERSION: v2.0.9

before_script:
  - apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl
  - curl -L# -f -o "/usr/local/bin/hasura" "https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/releases/download/${HASURA_VERSION}/cli-hasura-linux-amd64"
  - chmod +x "/usr/local/bin/hasura"

migrate-db-migration-dev:
  stage: migrate
  environment:
    name: dev/hasura
  script:
    - echo $DEV_HASURA_DATABASE
    - echo $DEV_HASURA_ENDPOINT
    - export HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT=$DEV_HASURA_ENDPOINT
    - export HASURA_GRAPHQL_ADMIN_SECRET=$DEV_HASURA_ADMIN_SECRET
    - echo ------------------- Checking status -------------------
    - hasura migrate status --database-name $DEV_HASURA_DATABASE --disable-interactive
    - echo ------------------- Done Checking status -------------------
    - echo ------------------- Applying Migrations -------------------
    - hasura migrate apply --up all --database-name $DEV_HASURA_DATABASE --disable-interactive
    - echo ------------------- Done Applying Migrations -------------------
    - echo ------------------- Preview Metadata -------------------
    - hasura metadata diff
    - echo ------------------- Done Preview Metadata -------------------
    - echo ------------------- Applying Metadata -------------------
    - ls -la
    - hasura metadata apply --log-level debug
    - echo ------------------- Done Applying Metadata -------------------
    - echo -------------------  Applying metadata reload -------------------
    - hasura metadata reload
    - echo ------------------- Done Applying metadata reload -------------------
  resource_group: dev-hasura
  only:
    refs:
      - dev
    changes:
      - migrations/**/*
      - metadata/**/*
      - seeds/**/*

migrate-db-migration-stage:
  stage: migrate
  environment:
    name: stage/hasura
  script:
    - echo $STAGE_HASURA_DATABASE
    - echo $STAGE_HASURA_ENDPOINT
    - export HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT=$STAGE_HASURA_ENDPOINT
    - export HASURA_GRAPHQL_ADMIN_SECRET=$STAGE_HASURA_ADMIN_SECRET
    - echo ------------------- Checking status -------------------
    - hasura migrate status --database-name $STAGE_HASURA_DATABASE --disable-interactive
    - echo ------------------- Done Checking status -------------------
    - echo ------------------- Applying Migrations -------------------
    - hasura migrate apply --up all --database-name $STAGE_HASURA_DATABASE --disable-interactive
    - echo ------------------- Done Applying Migrations -------------------
    - echo ------------------- Preview Metadata -------------------g
    - hasura metadata diff
    - echo ------------------- Done Preview Metadata -------------------
    - echo ------------------- Applying Metadata -------------------
    - hasura metadata apply
    - echo ------------------- Done Applying Metadata -------------------
    - echo -------------------  Applying metadata reload -------------------
    - hasura metadata reload
    - echo ------------------- Done Applying metadata reload -------------------
  resource_group: stage-hasura
  only:
    refs:
      - stage
    changes:
      - migrations/**/*
      - metadata/**/*
      - seeds/**/*
```

Comment: Why `alpine` image? Why not `debian` or other glibc-based docker?

Comment: @AlexYu updated.